# Cucumber - gherkin annotation with parameter

Tags: java, annotations, cucumber, gherkin

I would like to be able to pass a parameter using a gherkin scenario annotation. 
For example:

```
@xxx.1
Scenario: Log in and log out
```

I would like to have annotation @xxx which will get the number 1 as parameter.
So far i am only able to get all annotation and filter it one by one. I also tried to search for some plugin which can do such thing, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Have you tried using a scenario outline?

Answer (score 0):

If you add "annotations" (like `@xxxx.1` in your example) above your scenario, Cucumber will interpret those as tags. You can use tags to select which scenarios to run.

In order to pass a variable from Gherkin to your step definition, you will have to set the variable in your step, and specify in your step definitions which type of variable to use and how.

For example

```
Scenario: Log in and log out
  Given Log in and out as xxx.1
```

You step definition would be something like

```
@Given("Log in and out as {string}")
```

public void loginLogout(String user) {
// log in and out as that user
}

In addition, I'd consider describing more meaningful behaviour in your Cucumber scenarios. For example, I image a user of a certain type wants to log into the system to *do something* and you want to test that that works, or that it works only if they have a certain role.

For example:

Scenario: User wants to accomplish a task
  Given User has a registered account
  When they change their address
  Then their address is updated

Scenario: Admin is allowed to do a thing
  Given User has admin access
  When they do the thing the admin is allowed to do
  Then they are allowed to do the thing

Scenario: Regular user is NOT allowed to do a thing
  Given User does not have admin access
  When they do the thing the admin is allowed to do
  Then they are not allowed to do the thing